# How can I move files on Arch Linux to a Windows Partition

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, mount, windows

I have my Arch Linux Partition on `/dev/sda1` and I have my Windows partition on `/dev/sda4`.
When I used Ubuntu I could easily move files from Ubuntu to my Windows system and access them.
However, whenever I mount my Windows system on Arch I don't have permissions to move the files, even as root. It says the Windows partition is a read-only filesystem. Can I change this?

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79551/88378) may be relevant.

Comment: Do you have an entry in fstab for your Windows partition?

Comment: Thanks for responded but I've worked around it now I made a swap partition that I move data between

Comment: A possibly tightly related question, and potential duplicate target: [Unable to perform write & execute actions on ntfs partition. Not even with root privilege. Using arch linux.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197202/unable-to-perform-write-execute-actions-on-ntfs-partition-not-even-with-root). _But_, to be picky, this question does not mention NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel has readonly support for NTFS, you use it with

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt.
```

Read-write support for Linux is realized by [`ntfs-3g`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G), likely not installed by default on Arch, which allows you to

```
mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt.
```

Comment: Read-write support has been implemented long ago.