# Unable to perform write & execute actions on ntfs partition. Not even with root privilege. Using arch linux.

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, ntfs

Unable to perform  write & execute actions on ntfs partition. `ls -l` shows that user have only the read permission. Group any others have non. i tried to copy some text from home to windows partition with root privileged. then an error is shown

```
[root@dazz dazz]# cp test.txt /run/media/dazz/943C95C53C95A332/        
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/run/media/dazz/943C95C53C95A332/test.txt’: Read-only file system
```

I tried the same with elementary os. no issues. i can read write and execute normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, your filesystem is mounted read-only. If you are using kernel NTFS driver, it does not mount filesystem read/write, as that is considered unsafe. Your best bet is to use ntfs-3g, which IIRC, does read/write mount by default and is considered safe for writing.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the ntfs partition in mounted in `/run/media/dazz/943C95C53C95A332/` so it can be *auto*mounted. In the case some distribution on default mount ntfs partitions with `read-only` flag and most with `no-exec` option.
You are able to remount partition manually with `-o rw,exec` or refer to your distro manual to set automount options.